# Gitlab-ci docker execute fails to patch which has line ending ^M

Tags: gitlab-ci, yocto

I'm facing an issue with patch not applying in Yocto due to line ending ^M with docker execute in gitlab-ci. Same patch applies fine with same docker image in my host. I tried executing dos2unix to the patch file before applying that also didn't help.